# A world where speed of light is slower than regular objects

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, refraction

The subject explains the question.

Any idea of what a universe would be like where speed of light is a lot slower? Like, slower than sound, aeroplane, bullets etc.

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherenkov_radiation

Comment: There's a game some people at MIT did a while ago exploring this. You might want to take a look: http://gamelab.mit.edu/games/a-slower-speed-of-light/

Comment: @jensenpaull I am wondering of everyday world, not the particular scenario of Cherenkov radiation. But you may explain more.

Comment: I think this far too counterfactual to analyze. Electromagnetism is involved in most everyday physics. *Everything* changes.

Comment: That low light speed would still be the speed limit. Otherwise, stuff gets *very* weird.

Answer (score 2):

The quickest way to get a handle on this would be to get an introductory book on special relativity which contains the key equations which all contain c, the speed of light. Then look at the equations and see what the consequences would be if c got small. In general:

If you were moving (as in a car) relative to other objects in your vicinity, you would see them squished into pancakes and everyone you looked at through the windows of the car would be moving very very slowly. In addition, the objects would appear rotated so for example as you passed a car coming in the opposite direction you could look out the side window and see part of the front end of the car as well as its side. A car trip which would ordinarily require an hour to go from one town to another would seem to take just a few minutes by your wristwatch- while a much longer time had passed for people outside your car.

Synchronizing clocks so they would all tell the same time would become nearly impossible because any time you looked at for example the courthouse clock tower you would be looking several minutes into its past, and if you were moving,  it and all the other clocks around you would slow down.

The power output of atomic reactors would fall to very low levels because as c gets small, E = mc^2 would get small too.

Comment: Interesting note about reactions. Would *all* chemical reactions be low energy (of they happened at all)?  $mc^2$ is the total energy content of a substance

Comment: @RC_23 yes they would.